# How can we access inherited class attributes in case of metaclasses

Tags: python, inheritance, python-2.x, metaclass, getattribute

Even though `var1` is a member of the `ChildClass` class, why am i not able to access `var1` using `ChildClass.var1`

```
class MyType(type):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        print('attr lookup for %s' % str(name))
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
class BaseClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = MyType
    var1 = 5
class ChildClass(BaseClass):
    var2 = 6
print(ChildClass.var2) #works
print(ChildClass.var1) #fails
```

I am getting the following error

```
AttributeError: 'MyType' object has no attribute 'var1'
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using Python 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `MyType` is a `type`, use `type.__getattribute__` instead of `object.__getattribute__`:

```py
class MyType(type):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        print('attr lookup for %s' % str(name))
        return type.__getattribute__(self, name)
```